# datetime Returning time values in timedelta or datetime format in python

Tags: python, list, datetime

I am using python `datetime` function in but it returning datetime in formats like `datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 16, 20, 49, 52, 881274)` and also `datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 5)` but when i am printing it shows`2019-09-16 20:56:12.238794`

```
 import datetime
 time1=datetime.datetime.now()
 time2=datetime.datetime.now()
 time=time2-time1
 print(time,time1)
 lis=[]
 lis.append(time)
 lis1=[]
 lis1.append(time1)
 print(lis,lis1)
```

Results:

```
 0:00:00.000005 2019-09-16 21:02:35.083003
 [datetime.timedelta(0, 0, 5)] [datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 16, 21, 2, 35, 83003)]
```

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is

Comment: suppose if we are adding two values 3+5 it will return 8 but if returns sumedvalue(8) like that it returns it makes little bit confusing and also we didn't need that right. So that only i asked that

Answer (score 1):

`datetime` objects have different `str` and `repr` representations:

```
>>> str(timezone.datetime.now())
'2019-09-16 17:39:14.802264'
>>> repr(timezone.datetime.now())
'datetime.datetime(2019, 9, 16, 17, 39, 17, 853441)'
```

`print(x)` calls `str(x)` implicitly. `list.__str__`, however, calls `repr(elmnt)` to display the list's elements, hence the different ouptuts. Use:

```
 print(repr(time1))
```

if you prefer that represenatation.